# One method performing two functions

Tags: c#, string

I have the following method:

```
public string Phase(string phase)
{
    return "Phase 1";
}
```

The thing is I need it to output 2 strings in 2 different labels:

"Phase 1"

"Phase 2"

Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you are trying to do? Are you trying to return two string values with the method? Plus what language are you using?

Comment: Is it not `return "Phase " + phase;`?

Comment: C#. 
Im asking if it is possible (or a good way) of using 1 method "Phase" to return 2 string values to 2 Labels.

Comment: @SimeonVisser, I have not got a method for phase to refer to, it is just hardcoded string.

Comment: @cameron How do you plan to **use** this method?

Comment: @ReedCopsey, simply outputting it to 2 labels in the main program from my class. Thats all.

Comment: @cameron Are the "labels" (strings) being set within the form, or is the form asking your class for two string values?

Comment: @ReedCopsey, the form is asking for the strings. Thats why the strings are returned. Does this answer your question or am I misunderstanding the question? Also, I believe I have received an answer to my problem, I am just trying to make it work with my solution as I am receiving syntax errors.

Comment: @cameron Just edited to show a (probably simpler) option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options to return multiple values.

For example, you could return an `IEnumerable<string>` (or some other collection).  You could also return a `Tuple<string,string>`.

```
public IEnumerable<string> Phase()
{
    yield return "Phase 1";
    yield return "Phase 2";
}
```

Or

```
public Tuple<string,string> Phase()
{
    return Tuple.Create("Phase 1", "Phase 2");
}
```

That being said, it might be simpler to use two separate methods (or properties) to return each string, instead of trying to force it into a single method call.

Another alternative would be to pass in an argument which allowed the method to choose which label to return:

```
public string Phase(int phase)
{
    switch(phase)
    {
        default:
            return "Phase 1";
        case 2:
            return "Phase 2";
    }

    // Or just
    // return "Phase " + phase.ToString();

}
```

---

Edit:

Given your comments, I would recommend a property that just returned an array:

```
public string[] Phases
{
    get { return new[] { "Phase 1", "Phase 2" }; }
}
```

You could then use this as:

```
var phases = this.month1.Phases;
this.lblPhase.Text = phases[0];
this.lblPhase2.Text = phases[1];
```

Comment: Very nice, worked first time. Much appreciated Reed! Ill remember to use array in the future too. Its good to sometimes see how others would combat these situations. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If the method is within the same scope (part of the same form) where your labels are, then within the method you can just set the values of the labels:

```
public void Phase(string phase)
{
    label1.Text = "Phase 1";
    label2.Text = "Phase 2";
}
```

If it is not within the same scope as your labels, and you are returning the values for the labels to be set to, you could use a tuple:

```
public Tuple<String, String> Phase(string phase)
{
    return new Tuple<string, string>("Phase 1", "Phase 2");
}
```

Then when you receive the value back from the return set the labels like this:

**Edited to reflect OP's redirection**

```
var answer = month1.Phase("Phase");
label1.Text = answer.Item1;
label2.Text = answer.Item2;
```

Comment: I have put the 
public Tuple<String, String> Phase(string phase)
{
    return new Tuple<string, string>("Phase 1", "Phase 2");
}
into my Month1 class.
Then in my main program I have the following: 

var answer = this.month1.Phase("Phase");

This is how I would do what you said, but tweak it so it could refer to my class.

Is this correct, as I have am getting syntax errors for the last code.

Comment: @cameron It's hard to say for certain, but that should be it. Assuming you create a month1 instance of the class as `Month1 month1 = new Month1();` What is the syntax error that you are getting?

Comment: @NorimSim, Yes, I have an instance of my class. How do you propose I implement your solution into the form now? Here is my code inside the Form:

var answer = this.month1.Phase("Phase");
Gives me error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: Month1.Phase(string) and Month1.Phase(string)

this.lblPhase.Text = String.Format("{0}", this.month1.Phase(""));
Gives me the same error

Comment: @cameron It is telling you that your Month1 class has two methods with the same name and the same arguments: both methods are called `Phase` with a `string` argument. C# can't distinguish what method you want to call, so it is giving an error. If you delete the one you previously had it should fix the error.

Comment: yes sorry, that method stub was a duplicate that I was working on (testing). I apologise! Now have the code as: string answer = month1.Phase("Phase"); with the error of cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Tuple<string,string>' to 'string'

Comment: @cameron That is because `month1.Phase("Phase");` returns a `Tuple<String, String>` so your answer must be of the same type: `Tuple<String,String> answer = month1.Phase("Phase");` or if you want you can use `var` and the compiler will figure out the type for you, then you can use the answer like I have in my solution.